# Dividing/Summing value from table based on key in row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I currently have a table, There is a column value  which I would like to split with a predefined logic

```
    Table 1

   ID     Column X    Column Y      
   1      X1          7           
   2      x1          0           
   3      x1          0            
   4      x1          0           
   5      x1          0           
   6      x2          2           
   7      x2          0           
   8      x2          0        
   9      x3          3           
   10     x3          0        
   11     x3          0           
   12     x4          7            
   13     x4          0           
   14     x4          0   
   15     x5          2
   16     x5          0
   17     x5          0
   18     x5          0
```

The value in column Y will always appear in the first row

There are 3 scenario to split the value.

1. If the value in column Y is larger than the count in column X. The value will be added by 1 from top down. Example: X1,X4
2. If the value in column Y is equal to the count in column X. All value in column YY will be 1. Example: X3
3. If the value in column Y is less than the count in column X.  The value will be split by a factor of 0.5 from top down. There will not be a scenario whereby the sum of all the 0.5 will be less than the value in column Y. Example: X2,X5

   ```
   Wanted Result       
   ID     Column X    Column YY     
   1      X1          2
   2      x1          2
   3      x1          1
   4      x1          1
   5      x1          1
   6      x2          0.5
   7      x2          0.5
   8      x2          1
   9      x3          1           
   10     x3          1           
   11     x3          1           
   12     x4          3           
   13     x4          2         
   14     x4          2           
   15     x5          0.5
   16     x5          0.5
   17     x5          0.5
   18     x5          0.5
   ```

Comment: Hi.  I have a solution, but not sure why for ID 6, 7, 8, the 0.5 in 6 and 7 precedes the 1 in 8 while in every other instance, the greater value of Y comes first.  Is that a typo or does it matter?

Comment: The assignment of the value matters from top down

Comment: Ok, Louis.  So what's the logic there for x2?  Looks like it runs counter to the other groups.

Comment: The 0.5 will start dividing running top down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an interesting exercise.  Requires window functions, so should be SS 2005 and up.  Would have to see more data to see if my logic breaks anywhere.  Here's a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32b9e/25

```
WITH cteBase
AS
(SELECT
          X,
          MAX(Y) AS MaxY,
          COUNT(*) AS Instances
 FROM
          Table1
 GROUP BY
          X),
cteValues
AS
(SELECT
          *,
          CASE
            WHEN MaxY < Instances THEN 0.5
            ELSE CEILING(MaxY * 1.00 / Instances * 1.00)
          END AS High,
          CASE
            WHEN MaxY < Instances AND (MaxY * 1.00) / (Instances * 1.00) % 0.5 = 0 THEN 0.5
            WHEN MaxY > Instances THEN MaxY / Instances 
            ELSE 1
          END AS Low
 FROM
          cteBase),
cteWithRowNums
AS
(SELECT
          t1.ID,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.X ORDER BY t1.ID) AS RowID,
          t1.X,
          v.High,
          v.Low,
          CASE
            WHEN MaxY < Instances THEN CEILING((MaxY * High) + 0.5)
            ELSE MaxY - (Instances * Low)
          END AS StartLowInstanceRowID
 FROM
          Table1 t1 INNER JOIN cteValues v
          ON t1.X = v.X
)

SELECT
          ID,
          X,
          CASE
              WHEN RowID <= StartLowInstanceRowID THEN High
              ELSE Low
          END AS YY
FROM 
          cteWithRowNums
ORDER BY
          ID;
```

**EDIT:** Cleared up some misunderstandings with the grouping of X values and incrementing of Y values.  Updated fiddle link and code.

**EDIT 2:** Think I caught an error in my logic when dealing with StartLowInstanceRowID for MaxY < Instances scenario.  Have updated code and fiddle link.

Comment: Hi VBlades, thanks for your prompt response but my value for column X is inconsistent and maybe substituted by values such as TTTiox99. Using a replace is not an option

Comment: Hi i think we have a misunderstanding when i meant the count of x. I am implying that x1 have 5 instance x2 has 3 instance and x3 has 3instance. I will still up your answer. Thanks for the effort dude

Comment: @Louis: Ok, man.  I get what you mean.  Updated my answer.  Sorry about the misunderstanding.  One of the super smart guys could probably do it better, but I think it's working.  Need to test with more data.  No worries, just a puzzle to me.  Hope it helps you.

Comment: @Louis: I think I caught a small error in my logic, so updated link.  Please check it out.  Sorry for that, just missed it.